# How to process images uploaded to s3 from froala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing, amazon-s3, froala

Froala is great it allows uploading to s3 directly, but how do I process the images before the upload?

I currently use paperclip and ImageMagick to process images uploaded via my site, but not sure how to do the same if the upload is direct from froala to s3.